# tkinter - Changing variables assigned to labels causes duplicate window

Tags: python, user-interface, variables, tkinter

I'm using python to interact with some excel spreadsheets. I have all that working and now I'm working on a UI using `tkinter`. I have 3 buttons one to pull the location of a data file, output file save location and I have a start button.

I'm trying to use a `tkinter.Label` to display the value of the first two buttons, example `"c:/user/data_file"`. However, when ever I get the variable from the user and try to update the GUI with it, a copy of the window is created with the updated information. I need it to update directly to the current window seamlessly. I've been working to try to resolve this, but I just can't figure it out. Below is the code for my `tkinter` stuff.

```
def main(): 

    def InputFilePrompt():
        global InputFileLocation
        InputFileLocation = askopenfilename()
        update()  

    def OutputFilePrompt():
        global OutputFileLocation
        OutputFileLocation = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
        update()

    def update():

        root = Tk()

        root.title("test")
        root.resizable(width=TRUE,height=TRUE)

        InputFile = Button(root, text = "input data", command = InputFilePrompt)
        InputFile.grid(row = 0,column = 0)

        InputFileValue = Label(root, text = InputFileLocation, bg = 'white')
        InputFileValue.grid(row = 1,column = 0)

        OutputFile = Button(root, text = "Compiled Data save loacation", command = OutputFilePrompt)
        OutputFile.grid(row = 4,column = 0)

        OutputFileValue = Label(root, text = "location: N/A", bg = 'white')
        OutputFileValue.grid(row = 5,column = 0)

        startButton = Button(root, text = "start", bg = 'light green', command = Excel)
        startButton.grid(row = 7)

        BlankUI = [0 for x in range(2)]
        for blankspace in range(2):
            BlankUI[blankspace] = Label(root, text = "")
        BlankUI[0].grid(row = 2)
        BlankUI[1].grid(row = 6)

        root.mainloop()   

    update()
```

Error:

[image: Picture of the Error]

Comment: You are explicitly creating a new window everytime `update` Is called.

Comment: To be more specific, your code calls `Tk()` every time `update()` gets called. Generally this is only ever done once it a `tkinter`-based GUI, usually as part of its start-up initialization. Suggest you look more closely at any of the many `tkinter` examples available on-line.

Comment: Another suggestion: Read and start following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It'll make your code more readable and maintainable. Beyond that, defining all those other functions inside the `main()` function is very unusual and unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the help/tips Martineau! Everything is now working and thank you for suggesting that style guide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that doesn't create the duplicate window. I've incorporated most of the suggestions I made in comments—except for the one about defining functions inside of other functions. The following still does this because doing so made it very easy to avoid using `global` variables (which are generally considered a poor programming practice).

Notice that there's no `update()` function. The values of the two `tkinter.Label`s are now being stored in two `tkinter.StringVar`s objects instead of in regular Python strings.  A `StringVar` is one of the `tkinter` so-called "Variable" classes. Their primary feature is that they will cause all widgets referencing them to automatically update themselves whenever their contents get changed. To use them in a `Label`, they're specified by using the `textvariable=` option (*instead* of the `text=` option) when the constructor is called.
Here's some [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) I found about them with more details on how they work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename

def excel():
    """ Undefined. """
    pass


def main():
    def get_input_file_location():
        input_file_location.set(askopenfilename())

    def get_output_file_location():
        output_file_location.set(asksaveasfilename(confirmoverwrite=False))

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('test')
    root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

    input_file_location = tk.StringVar()
    input_file_location.set('<undefined>')
    output_file_location = tk.StringVar()
    output_file_location.set('<undefined>')

    input_file = tk.Button(root, text="Input data",
                           command=get_input_file_location)
    input_file.grid(row=0, column=0)
    input_file_value = tk.Label(root, textvariable=input_file_location,
                                bg='white')
    input_file_value.grid(row=1, column=0)

    output_file = tk.Button(root, text='Compiled data save loacation',
                            command=get_output_file_location)
    output_file.grid(row=4, column=0)
    output_file_value = tk.Label(root, textvariable=output_file_location,
                                 bg='white')
    output_file_value.grid(row=5, column=0)

    startButton = tk.Button(root, text='start', bg='light green',
                            command=excel)
    startButton.grid(row=7)

    blank_ui = [tk.Label(root, text='') for _ in range(2)]
    blank_ui[0].grid(row=2)
    blank_ui[1].grid(row=6)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Trubsworth: Does this answer your question or at least help?

Comment: I guess I may of spoke too soon. How do I use the file locations? When I print out the input_file_location I get PY_VAR0. I'm trying to use this variable in my excel() function to point to the correct location of an excel sheet.

Comment: Never mind I was able to figure it out. I used the .get() function command in my excel function, by doing file_location = input_file_location.get(). I was able to pass " input_file_location" into the function by using command = lambda

Comment: Trubsworth: Thanks for accepting my answer. Wanted to mention I was impressed you knew about using `lambda` to get access to the `nput_file_location` variable in the `excel()` function. It's something that's needed fairly often in `tkinter` programs—I've seen it called ["The extra arguments trick"](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/extra-args.html).